# Adding descriptive stats to this plot

Tags: pandas, seaborn

In pandas/seaborn:

```
sns.distplot(combo['resubmits'], kde=False, bins=8)
plt.savefig("g1.png")
```

Makes a very pretty histogram. I want to include a textual "legend" showing the mean, stdev, n, etc **as numbers** in a box. You would think this is so common that there's a semi automatic way to do it but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [feature request for that](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/266).

However, note that using [`matplotlib.pyplot.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html), you can easily do it yourself for now.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.axvline(x, 0, y_max)
```

where `x=combo['resubmits'].mean()` and `y_max` is the maximal value of `hist(combo['resubmits'])`'s bins' values.

Comment: I think they are asking for something like [this](http://www.minitab.com/uploadedImages/Content/Products/Minitab_Statistical_Software/Quick_Start/QS4-4-graphical-summary-report-EN.jpg).